# How to disable route pre-rendering in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am using [route handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers).

I have a route such as `app/blog/rss.xml/route.ts`:

```
import { getBlogPosts } from '@/routines/getBlogPosts.ts';
import Rss from 'rss';

const SITE_URL = 'https://ray.run';

export const GET = async () => {
  const blogPosts = await getBlogPosts();

  const feed = new Rss({
    description: 'Lessons learned scaling Playwright test automation',
    feed_url: `${SITE_URL}/blog/rss.xml`,
    language: 'en',
    site_url: SITE_URL,
    title: 'Rayrun Blog',
  });

  for (const blogPost of blogPosts) {
    if (!blogPost.publishedAt) {
      continue;
    }

    feed.item({
      author: blogPost.author.name,
      date: blogPost.publishedAt,
      description: blogPost.description,
      guid: `${SITE_URL}/blog/${blogPost.guid}`,
      title: blogPost.title,
      url: `${SITE_URL}/blog/${blogPost.slug}`,
    });
  }

  return new Response(feed.xml(), {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/xml',
    },
  });
};
```

Next.js tries to pre-render this page when I run `next build`. How do I disable that?

I've already looked through documentation and there is no mention of this.

I should have mentioned that the problem is that it seems no matter what settings I set, Next.js *attempts* to pre-render the page, i.e. even if I add `export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";` the build fails with error complaining about `export const GET = async () => {}` failing.

`GET` fails during the build because the build environment does not have access to the database, i.e. I need to entirely skip `GET` during build.

The only way I found around this is checking if the variable is unset and returning dummy content, e.g.

```
export const GET = async () => {
  if (!process.env.POSTGRES_DSN) {
    return new Response('OK');
  }
  // ...
};
```

The same is also true for `sitemap.ts`.

Update: Turns out that for routes what Fabio suggested is the correct course of action. However, I was thrown off by the fact that `sitemap.ts` does not behave that way – it ignores entirely the `dynamic` attribute. I ended up rewriting `sitemap.ts` to `sitemap.xml/route.ts`

Comment: That is because `sitemap.ts` is not a valid name for a route handler. It should always be `/my-folder/route.ts`. If the answer was correct please accept it so people after you can profit from the information provided.

Comment: Confusingly, they have it as a special route https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/sitemap#generate-a-sitemap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in the documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers#static-route-handlers), route handlers are statically evaluated by default when using the GET method with the Response object.

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
 
export async function GET() {
  const res = await fetch("https://example.com/api/test");
  const data = await res.json();
  return NextResponse.json(data);
}
```

However if you want a dynamic route handler, one of the following requirements or configuration options need to be met:

- Using the `Request` object with the `GET` method.
- Using any of the other HTTP methods.
- Using [Dynamic Functions](https://nextjs.org/#dynamic-functions) like `cookies` and `headers`.
- The [Segment Config Options](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers#segment-config-options) manually specifies dynamic mode.

If none of the first three options suit your needs, you could use a segment configuration as seen in the example below:

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
 
export async function GET() {
  const res = await fetch("https://example.com/api/test");
  const data = await res.json();
  return NextResponse.json(data);
}

// forces the route handler to be dynamic
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```

Please note that stack overflow expects you to do a [certain degree on research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/8003058) yourself before posting a question, this answer is curated information from the official documentation, ultimately from the link you have provided yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear what's the problem I am solving in my original question. Yes, `export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";` makes the route dynamic, but the problem is that next.js still _attempts_ to pre-render it. I added details to the original question.